# asp.net MVC. Can't use void method without redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form and void post method.

```
<form id="frm_loadFile" action="/Home/LoadFileWhithChanges" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" style="margin-top: 40px;">
                <input type="file" style="width: 100%;" name="upload" value="Choose file"><br><br>
                <input style="width: 115px;" type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>

    [HttpPost]
    public void LoadFileWhithChanges(HttpPostedFileBase upload)
    {
                if (upload == null)
                {
                    Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('No file')</script>");
                    Response.Flush();
                    Response.End();

                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                   //...
                   Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('All done')</script>");
                    Response.Flush();
                    Response.End();

                    return;
                }
}
```

But when it calls `Response.Write` after alert my page redirects

I want stay on this page after `response.write/` How can I do this?

Comment: try `return new JavascriptResult { Script = "alert('No File');" };` instead of `Response.Write` method to show alert to user.

Answer (score 0):

You are posting a form, and receive a response. It doesn't matter that your action is `void`. The browser doesn't care how the response was generated on the server. It's only course of action is to display the result. If you want to stay in the same page, you should either:

1. return the same page from the action
2. post the form in AJAX, which, in the case of posting a file, requires a special technique, involving iframes. You can look it up on the web.

Comment: but why when I use Response.OutputStream.Write(arrByte, 0, arrByte.Length); to download file with void method without AJAX, I stay in current page?

Comment: @MrZverev when downloading a file (e.g. by clicking a link) the browser downloads a file, allowing you to save it, provided you send the correct content-type. this is different from posting a form.